# How to fix assign []byte of data in multiple assignment

Tags: api, http, go

How to fix this problem about datatype of this function.

Firstly, I'm new to Golang and am trying to learn it with some practice.  I created a function to handle a request/GET http response.

```golang
func connect(url, token string) (data byte) {
    var bearer = "Bearer " + token
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    res.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return data
}
```

The error warning.

```sh
cannot assign []byte to data (type byte) in multiple assignment
```

I just want the function to return raw data from API response

Comment: The best practice is to do the whole Tour of Go tour.golang.org including all exercises. Basic stuff like how the type system works are explained in depth there.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of your function is of type `byte`, whereas the return type of `ioutil.ReadAll` is `[]byte`. Those types do not match, where one is a byte and the other is a slice of bytes. Change the return type of `data` to `[]byte`, assuming that is what you wanted in the first place.

```
func connect(url, token string) (data []byte) {
    var bearer = "Bearer " + token
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    res.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return data
}
```